# Maximum overs for a bowler in reduced 14 overs match?

Tags: rules, cricket

How to calculate maximum overs for a bowler in reduced over match i.e T20 match reduces to 14 or 13 overs?
Can two bowlers play 4 overs and the other 3 bowlers play 2 overs per each in 14 over match?

Answer (score 1):

As always, this depends on the playing conditions for the tournament you are in. However, we can take the [current T20 International playing conditions](https://pulse-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/document/2017/10/05/827e3bdd-6306-404e-8c62-47ae2f0ea223/ICC-Men-s-T20I-Playing-Conditions-2017-Code-FINAL-051017.pdf) as a guide:

> In a delayed or interrupted match where the overs are reduced for both teams or for the team bowling
>   second;
>
> for innings of rescheduled length of at least 10 overs, no bowler may bowl more than one-fifth of
>   the total overs allowed. Where the total overs is not divisible by 5, one additional over shall be
>   allowed to the maximum number per bowler necessary to make up the balance.

or for 14 overs, 4 bowlers may bowl 3 overs each and one bowler may bowl 2 overs.